# What does '$.' (dollar dot) mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I did `$..class` and it shows that it's a Fixnum, but I'm not sure how that value is derived. Here is part of the snippet

```
csv_files.each do |csv_file|
  method, year, currency_col = nil, nil, nil

  CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true) do |row|

    if $. == 2
      method_col, year_col, currency_col = "Method", "Year", "Correct Currency"
      method_col2, year_col2             = "Quotation Method", "Fiscal Year"
      validate_headers(csv_file, row, [method_col, year_col, currency_col], [method_col2, year_col2, currency_col])

      method = row[method_col] || row[method_col2]
      year   = row[year_col]   || row[year_col2]
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's the current line number of the most recently read filehandle](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/globals_rdoc.html).